# Не работает @import в gulp

Tags: gulp, sass

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Почему-то выбивает вот такую ошибку, никак не могу понять с чем это связано. Проверил все пути, вроде все нормально, а ошибка есть.

Код:

```
var gulp           = require('gulp'),
        gutil          = require('gulp-util' ),
        sass           = require('gulp-sass'),
        browserSync    = require('browser-sync'),
        concat         = require('gulp-concat'),
        uglify         = require('gulp-uglify'),
        cleanCSS       = require('gulp-clean-css'),
        rename         = require('gulp-rename'),
        del            = require('del'),
        imagemin       = require('gulp-imagemin'),
        pngquant       = require('imagemin-pngquant'),
        cache          = require('gulp-cache'),
        autoprefixer   = require('gulp-autoprefixer'),
        fileinclude    = require('gulp-file-include'),
        gulpRemoveHtml = require('gulp-remove-html'),
        bourbon        = require('node-bourbon'),
        ftp            = require('vinyl-ftp'),
        notify         = require("gulp-notify");

gulp.task('browser-sync', function() {
    browserSync({
        server: {
            baseDir: 'app'
        },
        notify: false
    });
});

gulp.task('sass', ['headersass'], function() {
    return gulp.src('app/sass/**/*.scss')
        .pipe(sass({
            includePaths: bourbon.includePaths
        }).on("error", notify.onError()))
        .pipe(rename({suffix: '.min', prefix : ''}))
        .pipe(autoprefixer(['last 15 versions']))
        .pipe(cleanCSS())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('app/css'))
        .pipe(browserSync.reload({stream: true}))
});

gulp.task('headersass', function() {
    return gulp.src('app/header.scss')
        .pipe(sass({
            includePaths: bourbon.includePaths
        }).on("error", notify.onError()))
        .pipe(rename({suffix: '.min', prefix : ''}))
        .pipe(autoprefixer(['last 15 versions']))
        .pipe(cleanCSS())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('app'))
        .pipe(browserSync.reload({stream: true}))
});

gulp.task('libs', function() {
    return gulp.src([
        'app/libs/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js',
        'app/libs/owl.carousel/dist/owl.carousel.min.js',
        'app/libs/jQueryFormStyler/jquery.formstyler.min.js',
        'app/libs/slimmenu-master/src/js/jquery.slimmenu.js',
        'app/libs/jqUI-slider/jquery-ui.min.js',
        // 'app/libs/magnific-popup/magnific-popup.min.js'
        ])
        .pipe(concat('libs.min.js'))
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('app/js'));
});

gulp.task('watch', ['sass', 'libs', 'browser-sync'], function() {
    gulp.watch('app/header.scss', ['headersass']);
    gulp.watch('app/sass/**/*.scss', ['sass']);
    gulp.watch('app/*.html', browserSync.reload);
    gulp.watch('app/js/**/*.js', browserSync.reload);
});

gulp.task('imagemin', function() {
    return gulp.src('app/img/**/*')
        .pipe(cache(imagemin({
            interlaced: true,
            progressive: true,
            svgoPlugins: [{removeViewBox: false}],
            use: [pngquant()]
        })))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/img')); 
});

gulp.task('buildhtml', function() {
  gulp.src(['app/*.html'])
    .pipe(fileinclude({
      prefix: '@@'
    }))
    .pipe(gulpRemoveHtml())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/'));
});

gulp.task('removedist', function() { return del.sync('dist'); });

gulp.task('build', ['removedist', 'buildhtml', 'imagemin', 'sass', 'libs'], function() {

    var buildCss = gulp.src([
        'app/css/fonts.min.css',
        'app/css/main.min.css'
        ]).pipe(gulp.dest('dist/css'));

    var buildFiles = gulp.src([
        'app/.htaccess'
    ]).pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));

    var buildFonts = gulp.src('app/fonts/**/*').pipe(gulp.dest('dist/fonts'));

    var buildJs = gulp.src('app/js/**/*').pipe(gulp.dest('dist/js'));

});

gulp.task('deploy', function() {

    var conn = ftp.create({
        host:      'hostname.com',
        user:      'username',
        password:  'userpassword',
        parallel:  10,
        log: gutil.log
    });

    var globs = [
    'dist/**',
    'dist/.htaccess',
    ];
    return gulp.src(globs, {buffer: false})
    .pipe(conn.dest('/path/to/folder/on/server'));

});

gulp.task('clearcache', function () { return cache.clearAll(); });

gulp.task('default', ['watch']);
```

Comment: Можно увидеть код из вашего gulp файла?

Comment: @And Rey конечно  https://jsfiddle.net/ud39u8ng/

Comment: Может с файлом font-awesome.min.css что то, проверьте наличие файла, проверьте путь подключения. Если вы его подключаете в каком то sass файле, то попробуйте вынести в файл concat после компилирования sass.

Answer (score 1):

Компилятор SASS в CSS не может найти файл font-awesome.min.css. Попробуй в директиве @import убрать .css в конце.
т.е. если у тебя @import "/app/example.css" отредактировать в "/app/example".

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте в импорте использовать одинарные кавычки вместо двойных
@import 'mixins';
@import 'variables';

Comment: решил проблему тем, что заменил ../ на app/ и все заработало) По идее должно работать именно с точками и мне такой файл скинули, значит у того, кто его делал, так работало, но решил попробовать поменять путь и оно заработало)

Comment: Вероятнее всего, путь идет от gulpfile.js, а он скорее всего был вне app, соответственно изменение пути и заставило работать код как следует